# Can The 5-Op Log2(Int 32) Bit Hack be Done in Java?

Tags: java, math, optimization, types, bit-manipulation

Just to clarify this is NOT a homework question as I've seen similar accusations leveled against other bit-hackish questions:

That said, I have this bit hack in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int __FLOAT_WORD_ORDER = 0;
const int __LITTLE_END = 0;

// Finds log-base 2 of 32-bit integer
int log2hack(int v)
{
  union { unsigned int u[2]; double d; } t; // temp
  t.u[0]=0;
  t.u[1]=0;
  t.d=0.0;

  t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==__LITTLE_END] = 0x43300000;
  t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER!=__LITTLE_END] = v;
  t.d -= 4503599627370496.0;
  return (t.u[__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==__LITTLE_END] >> 20) - 0x3FF;
}

int main ()
{
  int i = 25; //Log2n(25) = 4
  int j = 33; //Log2n(33) = 5

  printf("Log2n(25)=%i!\n",
         log2hack(25));
  printf("Log2n(33)=%i!\n",
         log2hack(33));

  return 0;
}
```

I want to convert this to Java.  So far what I have is:

```
public int log2Hack(int n)
    {
        int r; // result of log_2(v) goes here
        int[] u = new int [2]; 
        double d = 0.0;
        if (BitonicSorterForArbitraryN.__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==
                BitonicSorterForArbitraryN.LITTLE_ENDIAN) 
        {
            u[1] = 0x43300000;
            u[0] = n;
        }
        else    
        {
            u[0] = 0x43300000;
            u[1] = n;
        }
        d -= 4503599627370496.0;
        if (BitonicSorterForArbitraryN.__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER==
                BitonicSorterForArbitraryN.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
            r = (u[1] >> 20) - 0x3FF;
        else
            r = (u[0] >> 20) - 0x3FF;

        return r;
    }
```

(Note it's inside a bitonic sorting class of mine...)

Anyhow, when I run this for the same values 33 and 25, I get 52 in each cases.

I know Java's integers are signed, so I'm pretty sure that has something to do with why this is failing.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this 5-op, 32-bit integer log 2 to work in Java?

P.S. For the record, the technique is not mine, I borrowed it from here:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogIEEE64Float

Comment: Correction: Java's integers are signed. As a matter of fact, every primitive numeric data type except `char` is signed.

Comment: Use `>>>` for a logical right shift that does not repeats the sign.

Comment: Sorry Sanjay that's what I meant to say (that they're signed).... I'm changing the text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're in Java, can't you simply do `31 - Integer(v).numberOfLeadingZeros()`? If they implement this using `__builtin_clz` it should be fast.

Comment: Nice!! Great idea, I hadn't read about that feature... I'm basically teaching myself Java, have read Oracle's beginners docs, etc. but still don't know some things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not get the meaning of that code. The C code uses a *union* - a struct that maps the same memory to two or more different fields. That makes it possible to access the storage allocated for the double as integers. In your Java code, you don't use an union but two different variables that are mapped to different parts of memory. This makes the hack fail.

As Java has no unions, you had to use serialization to get the results you want. Since that is quite slow, why not use another method to calculate the logarithm?

Comment: Any suggestions other than a lookup table for a lower op alternative to simply bit shifting my value (the obvious and easy fix)?

Comment: @Jason On the page you linked, there are other approaches one might consider to use. But, what's the problem with the lookup table-approach on that page you linked?

Comment: The only other method listed was a shifting based method that while slightly faster than the traditional method was much slower than the other bit hack methods, including the table.

The lookup table is okay (7 ops for 32 bit), but I was wondering if anyone had seen any other faster novel Java log2 hacks, e.g. like another 5 op one...

Comment: Actually the mtrw's solution is probably better than a bit hack as its both fast and uses built-in features to the language -- thanks for the clarification, though.  For argument's sake, do you think you could just do some sort of typecasts to handle the double/integer identity exchanges? (I'm not sure if there's a way to do a bit-driven typecast in Java...)

Comment: @Jason Java is designed to be a portable language. There is no cast that keeps the memory layout rather than the value. As I said, you have to use serialization for this, but that is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the union to convert your pair of ints into a double with the same bit pattern. In Java, you can do that with [Double.longBitsToDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble%28long%29), and then convert back with [Double.doubleToLongBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29). Java is always (or at least gives the impression of always being) big-endian, so you don't need the endianness check.

That said, my attempt to adapt your code into Java didn't work. The signedness of Java integers might be a problem.